# Example of array.map() in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, dictionary

Consider the following common JavaScript construct

`var ages = people.map(person => person.age);`

Giving the desired result, which is an array of ages.

What is the equivalent of this in **C#**? Please include a simple example. The documentation indicates `select` or possible `selectAll` but I can't find an example online or any other SO question which can be pasted in and works.

If possible, give an example which turns the following array `{1,2,3,4}` into the following `{'1a','2a','3a','4a'}`. For each element, append "a" to the end, turning it from an Integer to a String.

Comment: `(new[]{1,2,3,4}).Select(v => String.Format("{0}a", v))`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You missed the `.ToArray()` on the end.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

This is called projection which is called `Select` in LINQ. That does not return a new array (like how JavaScript's `.map` does), but an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can convert it to an array with `.ToArray`.

```
using System.Linq; // Make 'Select' extension available
...
var ages = people.Select(person => person.Age).ToArray();
```

`Select` works with all `IEnumerable<T>` which arrays implement. You just need .NET 3.5 and a `using System.Linq;` statement.

For your 2nd example use something like this. Notice there are no arrays in use - only sequences.

```
 var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(num => string.Format("{0}a", num));
```

Comment: on c#6 : `var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(num => string.Format($"{num}a"));`

Comment: @BartCalixto - you don't need the string.Format... `var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(num => $"{num}a");`

Answer (score 32):

Only for info, if `people` is a `List<Person>`, the `ConvertAll` method is pretty similar to JS's `map`, e.g:

```
var ages = people.ConvertAll<int>(person => person.age);
```

But if you have an Array and you want to use any `List<T>` methods, you can easily achieve that by converting your variable into a List from Array, e.g:

```
var ages = people.ToList().ConvertAll<int>(person => person.age);
```

And finally, if you really need an Array back, then you could convert it back, e.g:

```
var ages = people.ToList().ConvertAll<int>(person => person.age).ToArray();
```

But that last example is not as good as the other answers, and you should use `Select` if you're working only with Arrays. But if you can, I suggest you to move to `List<T>`, it's much better!

Comment: convert to List and use ConvertAll allow me to refactor my large Select code that is not allow to have parameter constructor in Linq

Answer (score 5):

The LINQ extension methods on collections give you a host of really handy utilities. `Select` is one of them:

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<string> list = arr.Select(el => el + "a");
string[] arr2 = list.ToArray();

foreach (var str in arr2)
    Console.Write(str + " ");
```

This should output:

```
1a 2a 3a
```

This can safely be condensed to a 1-liner:

```
string[] arr2 = arr.Select(el => el + "a").ToArray();
```

A working example:

https://ideone.com/mxxvfy

Related docs:

[Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

[Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

Comment: How this is different from @Richard Schneider's answer. Also what's the need to do ToList()??

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to perform conversion to/from an array `Array.ConvertAll` can to the work. It is declared in `Array` class of `System` namespace (remember to add `using System;` at the top of the file) as:

```
public static TOutput[] ConvertAll<TInput,TOutput> (TInput[] array, Converter<TInput,TOutput> converter);
```

Example:

```
var items = new[] {"abc", "ab", "abcde"};

var result = Array.ConvertAll(items, p => p.Length);
            
Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result)); // Outputs 3, 2, 5
```

Method reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-5.0

Check this section to see .NET version compatibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.convertall?view=net-5.0#applies-to

Answer (score 2):

Linq's `.Select` is the `map` equivalent and `.Aggregate` is the `fold` equivalent.

```
var nums = new[] {1,2,3,4};
string[] r = nums.Select(x => x + "a").ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keywords `from`, `select`, `in` and `while`;
Or for your example:

```
 var ages = (from person in people select person.age).ToArray();
```

So essentially the syntax would be:

```
 <<list-output>> = (from <<var-name>> in <<list-input>> select <<operation>>);
```